# Show / Hide Nested Divs inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a div with sub divs to create a nested grid system. 
There are three levels in total:

1. MainDiv - Always Visible
2. SecondDiv - Show or hide when clicked on MainDiv
3. ThirdDiv - Show or hide when clicked on SecondDiv

   ```
   <div class="container padding" style="background-color: #fff;" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col col-75" >
               Department / Product Type
           </div>
           <div class="col col-25">
               Qty
           </div>
       </div>

       <div ng-repeat="item in departments | orderBy:'-qty'" style="padding:0px;margin: 0;">
           <div class="row" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
               <div class="col col-75" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
                   {{item.departmentName}} - {{item.productTypeName}} - Need Click here
               </div>
               <div class="col col-25" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size: 14px;font-weight:bold;padding:0;margin:0;">
                   {{item.qty}}
               </div>
           </div>
           <div ng-repeat="style in item.styles" style="padding:0;margin: 0;">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col" style="margin-left: 5% !important;border-top-width:0;border-bottom-width:0;">
                       {{style.styleNum}} ({{style.qty}}) - Need Click here
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row" ng-attr-id="{{ 'level-2-' + $index }}">
                   <div class="col col-5" style="border:0"></div>
                   <div class="col col-5" style="border-left:0;border-bottom:0;border-right:0;"></div>
                   <div class="col col-25">Color</div>
                   <div class="col col-25">Size</div>
                   <div class="col">Product#</div>
               </div>
               <div ng-repeat="styleLine in style.details">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col col-10" style="border:0;"></div>
                       <div class="col col-25">{{styleLine.color}}</div>
                       <div class="col col-25">{{styleLine.size}}</div>
                       <div class="col">{{styleLine.productNum}}</div>
                   </div>
               </div>

           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Now I need to add a click event on the div to show hide the necessary nested divs.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/z3RiV6cDFC6YjrbuqxN9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic example using **ng-init** and **ng-click**:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in items" ng-init="show = false">
    <div ng-click="show = !show"></div>
    <div ng-repeat="sub in obj.children" ng-show="show">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works great when you want to show all or nothing. How can I change this to show individual rows, but hide others based off the users actions?

Comment: @skone There isn't really much of a trick to it, here is a version of your original plunker doing it the way I described: http://embed.plnkr.co/1efAKIIk17BZkR3z5n4f/preview